# swift 2 how to use variable outside the function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a class ApiManager() that make request to JSON data in which I learned from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc-OlpOiPAY), which used protocol delegate approach to pass the data to ViewController class

The data is acquired fine but I am not sure how to use it around?! in this case I am trying to use it inside TableView

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, ApiManagerDelegate{

var names:[String] = []  // the variable which will hold the JSON data

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //instantiate the ApiManager Class
    //Set the ViewController as its delegate
    //perform request to Restaurants info
    
    let manager = ApiManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.getRestaurantsData()

    func didReceiveResponse (info: [String : AnyObject]){
        
        //Read name property from data dictionary (JSON)
        
        if let restaurantsData = info["restaurants"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            
            for restaurant in restaurantsData{
                let name = restaurant["name"] as? String
                self.names.append(name!)
            }
        }
        
 
        print("Data1: \(names)") // prints the data perfectly
        
    }

    func didFailToReceiveResponse() {
        print("There was an error in recieving API data")
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (names) //no data here
    return names.count //not working
}
```

I am a bit confused how to work around this, I tried to make return value to didReieveResponse(), but the issue is when I call the function it needs the argument (which is passed to it in the Delegator class "dictionary").. I am completely confused.

Here is the delegator class and protocol for reference:

```
import UIKit

//Custom Protocol Declaration
@objc protocol ApiManagerDelegate {
    optional func didReceiveResponse(info: [ String : AnyObject ])
    optional func didFailToReceiveResponse()
}


class ApiManager: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {

//open restaurant web API
private let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://some-url-here.com")

var delegate: ApiManagerDelegate?

override init() {
    
    super.init()
    
}

func getRestaurantsData() {
    
    let defaultConfigObject = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    
    let defaultSession = NSURLSession (configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue ())
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60 )
    
    

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type" )
    
    let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        
            if let responseError = error {
               
                self.delegate?.didFailToReceiveResponse?()
                print("Reponse Error: \( responseError )" )
                
                } else {
                    do {
                        let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                        
                        self.delegate?.didReceiveResponse?(dictionary)
                        //print( "Response: \( dictionary )" )
                        print("Response: Success")
                        
                    } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                        // Handle parsing error
                        self.delegate?.didFailToReceiveResponse?()
                        print( "JSONError: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            })
            
            dataTask.resume()
}
```

}

thanks,

---

### **Update:**

For future Developers who might suffer like me, the solution is to use TableViewName.reloadData() as mentioned below..
But please notice, it did only worked with me when I placed DidRecieveResponse() function outside ViewDidLoad, not sure why Hopefully one of the experts can explain it later.

Enjoy!

Comment: You defined the methods in your ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: you can use closures for callback

Comment: Could it be because the names doesn,t exists when the tableview is drawn?  Maybe it helps to reload data in tableview after viewdidload, or get the names in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Guys take it easy on me I am newbie XD, but yes I used the method inside viewdidload.

Comment: @TomTallakSolbu, I am not sure, but how to reload the data?

Comment: tableview.reloaddata() ;-)

Comment: tableview.reloadData()
i think you should use follow this tutorial for API calls and JSON handling

https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: Guys thank you, it appears reloaddata() was the solution, it was not working yesterday because the function was inside ViewDidLoad, when I moved it out it works perfectly! Many thanks.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
 class ViewController: UITableViewController, ApiManagerDelegate{

var names:[String] = []  
 let manager = ApiManager()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.getRestaurantsData()
 }

   func didReceiveResponse (info: [String : AnyObject]){

        //Read name property from data dictionary (JSON)

        if let restaurantsData = info["restaurants"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{

            for restaurant in restaurantsData{
                let name = restaurant["name"] as? String
                self.names.append(name!)
            }

                print("Data1: \(names)") // prints the data perfectly
             if (self.names.count>0)
             { 
              yourtableview.reloadData()
             }
        }

    }


  func didFailToReceiveResponse() {
    print("There was an error in recieving API data")
}
```

Comment: if I got it right, you want me to put manager = ApiManager() outside viewdidload. I just tried and tested but no output

Comment: this is initilization of ApiManager class, where you need add  does not a problm

Comment: ok, I made tableView.reloadData().. not working am not sure If I did it right!
yourtableview = tableview identifier?

Comment: your tableview == yourtableviewName ,

Comment: so this is the name = mainList
@IBOutlet var mainList: UITableView!

still not working

Comment: what the result u get here `print("Data1: \(names)") `

Comment: I dont know what have happened but suddenly there is no data!
the response from JSON is fine, I return it back to the way it was, but still empty.. very strange!

Comment: ok relax, the method `didReceiveResponse` is called , if yes are you get the answer from here `if let restaurantsData = info["restaurants"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]`

Comment: sorry, I dont understand you mate

Comment: this function is called or not func didReceiveResponse (info: [String : AnyObject]){

Comment: yes its called, its still the same code as above, if that's what you mean. I put print inside the for loop -> there is no output, I put it inside the function -> there is no output. not sure whats wrong

Comment: I think the class is unable to call the function, the print itself is not printing anything even a string, its like the class is not seeing the function! and one more thing the xcode is not auto completing the function name "didReceiveResponse" like before

Comment: then problem is in here    if let restaurantsData = info["restaurants"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{,  check once the data is ret

Comment: Hi again, I realized the reason why it was not working because it was inside ViewDidLoad (strangley was working before!). Now I moved it outside its working again. restaurantData give me output, and I used tableview.reload() and it works!! thanks mate!

Comment: I think you should edit your answer and put DidRecieveResponse function outside ViewDidLoad, to make perfect answer for future newbies :)
Thanks Again!

Comment: @Engineeroholic -- happy to hear bro, but `DidRecieveResponse` is alredy available in outside bro, any way congrats, if my answer is useful give the tick mark and upvote the answer it s useful for others

Comment: Hahahah it was missunderstanding then brother! thanks!

Comment: @Engineeroholic -- ha ha , welcome bro, and nice to meet with you

Comment: nice to meet you too :)